# Softmax function and symmetry in feature space assumption

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

In order to make an optimization problem tractable. a symmetry in feature space assumption is made. Based on this assumption, then if we have two nodes: node A and its neighboring node, node B (B is a neighbor of A), then they both have a symmetric effect over each other in feature space. Accordingly, the conditional likelihood of observing node B given node A is modeled as a softmax unit parametrized by a dot product of their features (vectors)? How does the softmax function and the symmetry assumption relate to each other?

Comment: Can you define symmetry in this context? I am confused by what it means for nodes to "have a symmetric effect over each other in feature space".

Comment: The problem is to learn node representations for nodes in a network. The problem is formulated as a maximum likelihood problem. However, in order to make the optimization problem tractable, the authors are making two assumptions, where one of them is the symmetry in the feature space. The goal is to maximize the likelihood for observing a neighboring node given the feature representation of the source node. I am referring to Section 3 in this paper: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369018/softmax-function-and-symmetry-in-feature-space-assumption

Comment: Did the author of this question gain some insight to share ? Thanks.